# Gauss' Theorem and I want to show that $ \iint_{\theta E} f \nabla f \cdot \vec{n} d \sigma=\iiint_{E}|\nabla f|^{2} $

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Suppose $f(x, y, z): \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^{2}$ harmonic function, that is, it satisfies $f_{x x}+f_{y y}+f_{z z}=0 .$ Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a region to which Gauss's Theorem can be applied. I want to show that
> $$
> \iint_{\partial E} f \nabla f \cdot \vec{n} d \sigma=\iiint_{E}|\nabla f|^{2}\mathrm{d}(x,y,z)
> $$
> where, as usual, $\nabla f=\left(f_{x}, f_{y}, f_{z}\right)$ is the gradient.

Can you help, how can I show?

## StayAtHome

Comment: Is $\theta E$  supposed to denote the boundary of the region $E$?

Comment: Also, what are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: The comment to stay at home is important, but not for the exercise.

Comment: Can you apply Gauss theorem to $F=f\nabla f$?

Comment: @Fakemistake Thanks, I trying to apply now, thanks :)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Probably, I couldn't apply Gauss theorem, now thanks to Fakemistake, I can apply Gauss. Thanks for comments :)

Comment: Where did you encounter the problem? The notation $\theta E$ is strange

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ohhh, sorry. I edited. Yes, denote the boundary of the region $E$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks again for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer notes, the identity $\nabla \cdot (f\nabla f) = |\nabla f|^2 + f[\nabla \cdot (\nabla f)]$ is useful.  Here's a proof of this identity:

\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot (f \nabla f) &= \sum_{i=1}^3 \hat e_i \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(f \nabla f) = 
\sum_{i=1}^3 \hat e_i \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(f \sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{\partial f}{x_j}\hat e_j\right)
\\ & = 
\sum_{i,j=1}^3 \hat e_i \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(f  \frac{\partial f}{x_j}\hat e_j\right) = 
\sum_{i,j=1}^3 (\hat e_i \cdot \hat e_j) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(f  \frac{\partial f}{x_j}\right)
\\ & = \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(f  \frac{\partial f}{x_i}\right)
= \sum_{i=1}^3\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} + f \cdot \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2}\right)
\\ & = |\nabla f|^2 + f[\nabla \cdot (\nabla f)]
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\text{div}(f\nabla f)=\nabla f\cdot \nabla f+f\Delta f,$$
where $\Delta f$ denote the Laplacian.